ReactJS: ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications
I'm seeing the following error when I submit a particular form:

This is happening when I submit a edit form but I don't see this error when I submit a add form.
I have checked thoroughly in my codebase I don't have used ResizeObserver in my entire application this is not happening with all the system but I get this on some particular systems. Currently I am using react version 18.
